# Override python built-in float() behavior

Tags: python, string, floating-point, exponent

Old title: Convert scientific notation string without 'e' to float in Python

I use a program that has some ...odd formats allowed. One format for real numbers is scientific notation without the letter character 'E'. For example, "-1.67E-6" could be written as "-1.67-6". Obviously, float() doesn't like this. I am writing many classes that would need this same check in multiple fields, so I'm in need of a function to do this cleanly. Is there a way to overwrite the builtin definition of float() so that it could handle this format? I think that would be ideal, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

My current work-around is to use my own string-to-float function that looks something like the following.

```
str2float(s):
    if re.search(r'([-+][0-9]*.[0-9]*)([-+][0-9]*)', s):
        base, exp = re.findall(r'([-+][0-9]*.[0-9]*)([-+][0-9]*)', X1)[0]
        s = f'{base}E{exp}'
    return float(s)
```

Comment: what is your example input and example output ?

Comment: I would like to call `float('-1.67-6')` and get an output of `-1.67e-06`

Comment: do you always have `-` after `e`? I mean, is there no case where you want `1.676` -> `1.67e06`?

Comment: Yeah how do you know if it’s positive or negative ?

Comment: In the case where the exponent is positive, it would be `1.67+6` > `1.67e06`. The data in question here is spatial (x, y, z) locations. Typically, exponentials only get thrown into the mix when it's a poorly formatted file that should be replaced by 0.000, but that's not something I'm in control of (yet).

Comment: Would something like `re.sub(r'(?<=\d)-(?=\d)', 'E-', '-1.67-6')` and `re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\+(?=\d)', 'E', '-1.67+6')` work?

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize `re.sub` in a way that also accounts for current valid scientific notation.

```
import re

def str_to_float(s: str) -> float:
    s = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)-(?=\d)', 'E-', s)
    s = re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\+(?=\d)', 'E', s)
    return float(s)

print(str_to_float('-1.67E-6')) # -1.67e-06
print(str_to_float('-1.67-6')) # -1.67e-06
print(str_to_float('1.67+6')) # 1670000.0
print(str_to_float('1.67E6')) # 1670000.0
print(str_to_float('-1.67')) # -1.67
print(str_to_float('1.67')) # 1.67
```

`(?<=\d)` -  positive lookbehind for a single digit (0 through 9).

`-` and `\+` -  match the characters `-` and `+` literally.

`(?=\d)` -  positive lookahead for a single digit (0 through 9).

This locates the invalid scientific notation (as `float` sees it) and replaces them with valid scientific notation.

Comment: I've written a function similar to this before. What I'm curious about is if it is possible to overwrite the built-in `float()` function/class to be able to handle my unique format. In addition to knowing if this is even possible, I'm also curious about what the best practice for this might be. I'll edit my question to reflect that I'm not looking for help with the regular expressions or writing a new function as I do already have something for this.

Comment: It IS possible to shadow the built-in `float` with your own implementation, HOWEVER, I would strongly advise against it if you are working in an environment where somebody else will be working with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found what I was looking for.

```
class float(float):
    def __new__(cls, s):
        if re.search(r'([-+]?[0-9]*.[0-9]*)([-+][0-9]*)', s):
            base, exp = re.findall(r'([-+]?[0-9]*.[0-9]*)([-+][0-9]*)', s)[0]
            s = f'{base}E{exp}'
        return super(float, cls).__new__(cls, s)
```

This appears to allow me to over-ride the base behavior of `float()` in the way that I'm desiring. Is this a good idea? Bad idea? Why?

Comment: 1. Whenever someone sees `float` they expect a certain type of behavior, whether it be an expected error or a `type` check in an unexpected way (`type(float('1.67')) is __builtins__.float`). 2. This adds extra overhead to creating a `float` and when done enough will significantly reduce performance. 3. There are situations you almost certainly didn't account for with this implementation. The built-in `float` has the benefit of being tested by millions of people. Virtually every edge case has been found. For example, yours breaks with something as simple as `float(2)`.

Comment: @Axe,
This is the type of response and feedback I was hoping for. I had a sneaking suspiction this would not be in line with best practices, but wanted to know what the reasoning behind this might be.